# jQuery-UI datepicker TypeError: o is undefined

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am not able to find out, why this error appears:
*TypeError: o is undefined jquery-ui.min.js:9:4005*

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.inputDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy',
    });
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<label class='required' 
    for='event_start'>Datum</label>
<input id='event_start' 
    class='inputDate' 
    name='event_start' readonly 
    value='22.04.2019'>
```

The included files in the head of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" media="screen"> </link>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
```

The datepicker widget appears, but nothing happens, after I choose a date. I see the above error message in firefox web developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of the problem:

The HTML element id="event_start" occurred several times in the code.

Jquery uses the id to map the datepicker to the proper input element although a class is defined as selector.